Is there a function or operator I can use to save the state of the text cursor and then "call" the cursor to "load" to the position saved?
cout << "\n4. How much does an " << item << " weigh in " << unit << "? Type here: ";
cout.flush();//promt is displayed immediately
cout << "\n      *Note that the format for entering the weight must only contain numerical digits";
cout << "\n      *The number can either be typed as a whole number or decimal number (e.g 1234 or 1234.0000)\n";
//Need something to reset the cursor back to "Type here: "
cin >> weight;

Notice the first cout in the block. I want the text cursor to revert to that spot ("Type here: cursor") whilst the cout asterisk statements printed prior to when cin waits for user input.
My idea is there is some kind of variable that stores a save state of the cursor, which would be declared after the first cout statement in my code snippet.
For context, I am working through a Linux terminal. From a post provided by the Community Bot, I looked up SetConsoleCursorPosition(), and learned that is a Windows-specific function.
How could I save the state of the text cursor and then "call" the cursor to "load" the saved state of the cursor?

For starters, while the existence of std::cout etc. might imply that something like a terminal is assumed (although it can be anything), it's definitely not standardized. So no, C++ itself doesn't handle this. And while there are libraries to support a multitude of terminals, I'd probably just go to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html and not bother with terminals that nobody uses (there are escape sequences to "Save cursor location" and "Restore cursor location"),

std::cout is an output stream which (roughly speaking) means a set of characters is written to it and (buffering aside) output to the output device (which may be a screen, a console window, a file, a pipe, etc) in the same order.  Not all devices support  positioning to a location on a screen, and neither does std::cout.  You either need to use system-specific functions - like SetConsoleCursorPosition() in the windows API - designed for screens, consoles, etc or a library like ncurses (which is not standard C++, but is supported for a number of (but not all) POSIX compatible systems)

Sounds to me like you want something like ncurses.
